# Risk assessment for using draw knife/shave horse with children?

Tags: safety, green-wood, draw-knife

I work at a school and we have a green woodwork area. Which is awesome!

I’d like to work towards using a shave horse and draw knives with the children there, aged 8-16 years.

I’ve used shave horses and draw knives a fair bit, but have also heard from different people that they are ‘very foolproof and safe’... but then from others, that you can get horrible injuries and they may be quite dangerous, like on this compendium of Newspaper cuttings of drawknife injuries:

https://blog.lostartpress.com/2016/03/05/the-deadly-knee-hating-drawknife/

I will need a written risk assessment in order to run this activity at schools, but I can’t find any publicly available online- has anyone seen/know of one?

Is a draw knife designed to be safely used with a shave horse, or can a draw knife be safely used without a shave horse?

Comment: Welcome to WSE. Just to clarify, any response to this question on this site should not be directly used in support of the safety of this devise with children at your school. We are a Woodworking Q&A, not a reference authority. I am not surprised you are not finding any definitive authoritative evaluations of the safety of drawknives with children. Their use is not common.  My first question was what tools does the school allow?  Knives, hatchets, saws, chisels....each tool requires certain safety disciplines.

Comment: *"Is a draw knife designed to be safely used with a shave horse, or can a draw knife be safely used without a shave horse?"* This part at least can be answered definitively. Yes a drawknife can be used without a shave horse, many people do use them that way these days, although in place of the shavehorse there must be a stout, reliable clamping arrangement of some kind. Note however that this does tend to make the work with them far less smooth and 'organic' — the key advantage of the foot-controlled clamping and release in a shavehorse is the swift and effortless shifting of the workpieces.

Comment: *"I’d like to work towards using a shave horse and draw knives with the children there, aged 8-16 years."* The guidelines for use of kitchen knives in schools might be a decent place to start here, since I know bare blades are verboten until a certain age in many places (for obvious, & very good reasons — kitchen-knife cuts can be very severe). Without any definitive guidelines about drawknives (from present-day authorities) I think someone is going to have to make a tough call here and be willing to stand by it if an accident occurs. Actually WHEN, since an accident is inevitable.... [contd]

Comment: ...given a long enough timeframe and sufficient numbers of users. Personally, although I hate over-tight restrictions overall, the possibly life-changing injuries possible with a drawknife should give serious pause. IMO it wouldn't be overly Nanny State to just not allow any child to use a drawknife under any circumstances, even under supervision. Even under *close* supervision. But obviously there's a case for more mature kids (let's say above 14?) to be allowed to use them; however the perceived risk and acceptance of risk in this sort of thing is immensely varied place to place.

Comment: Agree that guidelines should be drawn from existing work on other bladed tools (knives, chisels). Having survived the 8-16 range, I can assure you that anything sharp can be misused and (if you are a litigious venue — ahem, looking at you, America) create an injury lawsuit.

Comment: Can it be dangerous?  yes, but not any more dangerous than many other tools used in schools.  Most shop classes have a host of tools that would allow much faster and more serious damage, table saws, band saws, welders, etc.  So looking at how those are dealt with is a good idea.  I've taught 11 yo how to black smith and there you are swinging around 1900F steel.

Comment: Thanks for all these comments! Yes the school already does woodwork with children in that age bracket, using knives, bowsaws, folding saws, splitting axes and hatchets. I'm more wanting someone to flag up the key 'danger moments' to be aware of using specifically drawknife (with or without shave horse), ideally in risk assessment form, or just from personal experience, to minimise number of accidents and the severity of (inevitable) accidents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering based on your comment:

> Yes the school already does woodwork with children in that age bracket, using knives, bowsaws, folding saws, splitting axes and hatchets.

**I would argue that a drawknife is safer than knives, safer than axes and hatches.**

- With pocket/shaving knives there is always the risk (and sometimes necessity) to work the blade *towards* your fingers/hands, slipping and cutting yourself badly.
- With (carving) hatchets handling mistakes can easily endanger fingers.
- Splitting axes, when used unsafely, can lead to very serious injuries, e.g. in feet/legs when a swing misses or glances off. Or in fingers/hands in the good'ol *"I'll just hold this log by hand and will let go in time"*.

The drawknife by design requires two hands on the tool. This means:

- Your hands are safe since they are in no risk of ever coming near the blade.
- The workpiece needs to be fixed in a shaving horse / vice / clamp, so there is no (or lower) chance for risks due to unsafe holding of the work piece by hand. On a properly designed shaving horse your legs/knees should be well out of the way of any slipping blade, and I'd argue this is even more true for modern workbench clamps and vices.